# How can I remap Left ⌘ Command to Left Ctrl in VSCode on MacOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I am accustomed to mapping the left <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, supported by a configuration option in `iTerm2`, my default dev context.

I am learning `VSCode` and am wondering how to accomplish this mapping *within that application*.

I will upvote any answer that does the job, but in descending order of preference I seek a solution that:

1. requires neither an extension nor an external application
2. or requires an extension but no external application*
3. or requires an external application

*I use `vscodevim` so if there is a solution involving configuration of that extension, I would value such a solution.

---

**Why?**

I developed my muscle memory using PC-layout keyboards before switching predominantly Apple-layout keyboards. I also develop on multiple OSes and keyboard types, primarily in Vim, running in a terminal. I'd like the spatial location of key combinations to remain consistent across these contexts. Over on GitHub, [other users are also seeking an answer to this question](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/6322)

Comment: fyi, there's an existing Q&A about specifically VS Code's integrated terminal, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61762420/11107541. But I also wonder how much of that question is really about shells, which there are also specific questions about: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50104492/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69516464/11107541. And if you generalize the question away from VS Code and just about macOS, then there's already https://stackoverflow.com/q/75533/11107541.

Comment: okay... now that you've edited, can you clarify what separates this from being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61762420/11107541 then?

Comment: That question refers to the VS Code terminal *only*, I am wanting the remap within the entire application, especially the editor windows, the primary place where I'll make use of Vim keybindings. I would also want the remap to function in the terminal, but functioning there exclusively is inadequate to my needs.

Comment: Can you consider building `vscodevim` from source so that you have more control over the configuration?

Answer (score 3):

[Keybindings in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) allow you to remap actions within the editor but do not support remapping modifier keys at the OS or hardware level.

The [`vscodevim` extension](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) allows remapping keys within the context of Vim emulation (for Vim commands), but not the VSCode UI itself (not for general VSCode shortcuts, like saving a file or opening the command palette).

---

> I am aware of Karabiner and it is highly likely I will not be able to install this on my workplace machine.

#### Within VSCode *without* external tools

VSCode allows for extensive customization of keyboard shortcuts within the application itself through its `keybindings.json` file. However, it is limited to defining shortcuts for actions within VSCode and does not extend to modifying the behavior of the operating system's modifier keys.
That means you can reassign actions from using `⌘` to `Ctrl` within VSCode, but you cannot change the function of the `⌘` key to behave as a `Ctrl` key across the board within VSCode (even when limited to vscodevim).

For example, you could manually change shortcuts that typically use `⌘` on macOS to use `Ctrl` instead, through VSCode's Keyboard Shortcuts editor:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+c",
        "command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    // Add more custom bindings here
]
```

#### Considering work restrictions

A potential, albeit partial workaround, could involve getting creative with macOS's built-in capabilities, such as creating custom shortcuts in System Preferences for specific actions in VSCode. However, this does not achieve a true remap of the `⌘` key to `Ctrl` and would be very limited in scope, applying only to specific actions rather than a comprehensive key behavior change.

You might also consider discussing with your IT department the possibility of making an exception for a tool like Karabiner-Elements, especially if it is important for your productivity and ergonomics.
Alternatively, adapting to the default macOS shortcuts or customizing VSCode's shortcuts within the limitations outlined might be necessary.

---

#### For other users, *outside* the workplace environment:

For system-wide remapping of the `⌘ Command` key to `Ctrl`, you could try and use external tools like [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). That application allows you to remap keys at the OS level, affecting all applications, including VSCode.

Open Karabiner-Elements and go to the ['Simple Modifications' tab](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/configure-simple-modifications/). Click 'Add item' and select your device from the dropdown.
For '`From key`', choose `left_command`. For '`To key`', choose `left_control`.

Again: that method would remap the key for *all* applications, so it affects your entire MacOS environment, not just VSCode.

---

If that is too inconvenient, you would need a tool like [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/), a powerful automation tool for macOS that can detect the currently active application and execute scripts accordingly.

You can use Hammerspoon to monitor when VSCode becomes the active window and then trigger a script to activate a specific Karabiner-Elements profile or configuration and deactivate it when VSCode loses focus.

Open `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` in your text editor to add your custom Lua script for application monitoring. That script checks if VSCode is the active application and could be expanded to activate/deactivate a Karabiner-Elements profile via a shell command.

```lua
function applicationWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
  if (appName == "Visual Studio Code") then
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.activated) then
      -- VSCode is focused, activate Karabiner profile
      hs.execute("/path/to/activate_karabiner_profile.sh", true)
    elseif (eventType == hs.application.watcher.deactivated) then
      -- VSCode is not focused, revert Karabiner profile
      hs.execute("/path/to/deactivate_karabiner_profile.sh", true)
    end
  end
end

appWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationWatcher)
appWatcher:start()
```

You would also need to create scripts (e.g., `activate_karabiner_profile.sh` and `deactivate_karabiner_profile.sh`) that modify your Karabiner-Elements configuration to activate or deactivate the desired profile. That could involve using `defaults` commands to modify Karabiner's configuration files or using [Karabiner's CLI](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/misc/command-line-interface/) if available.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# That is a placeholder command. Update it to your actual command to switch profiles.
karabiner_cli --select-profile "VSCode"
```

Note: Karabiner-Elements does not directly support a CLI for dynamically switching profiles. You might need to directly manipulate its configuration files or explore alternative methods such as AppleScript or automating UI actions for profile switching.

Comment: I will edit my question to clarify, but my use case within VSCode is exclusively for vscodevim. Do you know a way I can configure vscodevim specifically to "commandeer" all Cmd keypresses and interpret them as Ctrl?

Comment: @Stew No, that is the general idea of my answer: not for general VSCode shortcuts. Hence my convoluted workaround.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was clear. I was asking if some configuration was available at the scope of the plugin, rather than at the VSCode application level.

Comment: @Stew Not that I know of. I have edited the answer to detail the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the GitHub issue ticket you linked, you can remap modifier keys at the system level. Ex. on Ventura, open the System Settings application, go to "Keyboard", then "Keyboard Shortcuts", then "Modifier Keys". Then you can switch <kbd>cmd</kbd> to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to send <kbd>cmd</kbd>. If this is about muscle memory from non-mac usage (and it sounds like it is), then I'd recommend that over doing things on a per-application basis.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, it's about muscle memory in specific contexts. In the context of Mac OS generally, I have a lot of muscle memory specific to `cmd`, e.g. switching between active applications. But for applications I use on a variety of OSes, I want the key combinations to have a consistent finger-pattern. This is why I've scoped it to specific applications. Thanks!